# How to learn about funeral customs while traveling in Australia

Tags: australia, international-travel, local-customs

Is there a way one could learn about the local funeral customs (irrespective of the religion of the deceased) while traveling through a country ?

In NT, Australia how could one go about learning the funeral customs of Aboriginal/Indigenous tribes ?

Comment: Could you change your title to be Australia-specific, perhaps to match the question content? Otherwise it'd be different in many countries - some will be open about it, other cultures are very sensitive about processes or customs.

Answer (score 2):

Approaches to death can differ significantly among Aboriginals. Your best bet would be to go to a good Aboriginal museum or cultural centre but some Aboriginal people believe that people effectively cease to exist after death so will not discuss anything related to it.

The [Aboriginal Australia Culture Centre](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g255063-d256782-Reviews-Aboriginal_Australia_Culture_Centre-Alice_Springs_Red_Centre_Northern_Territory.html) in Alice Springs has [a page](http://www.aboriginalart.com.au/culture/religion.html) that includes information about ceremonial behaviours, so I'd suggest that as a good and accessible starting point.  I haven't visited it myself to give you a first-hand report.